# Commonspot forms hidden field values

Tags: forms, coldfusion, commonspot

I have a form in commonspot, which uses hidden field to pass the information to next form,which it got from a previous form, but I'm not sure about the syntax for the default value of hidden fields. I have tried using `form.fieldname`, `evaluate(form.fieldname)`, and `#form.filedname#`.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks,
AA

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As Mark mentioned, seeing your code will help us better understand both the problem and the goal. Do not worry if the code is not working  :)  Just note what it is doing wrong what you would like it to do instead.

Answer (score 3):

Ardash - you should paste some actual code to help us understand what you mean.

In general if you want a "default" value (for the case where the item doesn't exist previously) you should use cfparam like so:

```
<cfparam name="form.myField" default="*some default value*"/>
```

Then in your hidden field you can safely do this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myField" value="<cfoutput>#form.myField#</cfoutput>"/>
```

Hope this helps. Paste some code for a better response :)

Comment: Actually, in commonspot if we give it as a coldfusion expression then its working instead of directly giving it

Comment: Be sure to use #htmlEditFormat(form.myField)# when you output your user input.  Otherwise, you're opening your site to a XSS attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the field names submitted to the page using this method:

```
<cfoutput>#form.fieldnames#</cfoutput>
```

alternatively, you can get the field names and data:

```
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

This might help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: Good tip ... but I always sort of avoid the "fieldnames" list. It's a legacy of CF 4 - the days before "form" was an struct. I suspect it will go away eventually. I'm always surprised when it's still there in the newest version (ha).